# Scrolling through a waveform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, waveform

I have a waveform visualiser I am trying to make for some audio editing, and need to be able to scroll through the wave form. The code I'm currently using comes from [this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1603418/how-to-create-waveform-texture-from-audioclip.html) and works after I made some modification to allow the specifying of a start audio time and end audio time:

```
public Texture2D PaintWaveformSpectrum(AudioClip audio, int textWidth, int textHeight, int audioStart, int audioEnd, Color col) {

        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(textWidth, textHeight, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        float[] samples = new float[audioLength];
        float[] waveform = new float[textWidth];
        audio.GetData(samples, 0);
        int packSize = ((audioEnd - audioStart) / textWidth) + 1;

        if (audioStart != 0) {
            audioStart += packSize % audioStart;
        }


        int s = 0;
        for (int i = audioStart; i < audioEnd; i += packSize) {
            waveform[s] = Mathf.Abs(samples[i]);
            s++;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < textWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < textHeight; y++) {
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, Color.gray);
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < waveform.Length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= waveform[x] * ((float)textHeight * .75f); y++) {
                tex.SetPixel(x, (textHeight / 2) + y, col);
                tex.SetPixel(x, (textHeight / 2) - y, col);
            }
        }
        tex.Apply();

        return tex;
    }
```

The issue here however, is that when I'm scrolling through the audio, the waveform changes. It does indeed scroll, but the issue is that it is now showing different values in the waveform. This is because there are significantly more samples than pixels, so there is a need to down sample. At the moment, every nth sample is chosen, but the issue is with a different start point, different samples will be chosen. Images below for comparison (additionally, [here's a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gX17jU9fTOokliqDD6YyT7PKF6j2N-VJ/view?usp=sharing). [This is what I want the scroll to look like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s6DJTmo8hGqSgO65sJhJc8JSilE32ziG/view?usp=sharing)):

[image]

As you can see they are slightly different. The overall structure is there but the waveform is ultimately different.

I thought this would be an easy fix - shift the start audio value to the nearest `packSize` (ie, `audioStart += packSize % audioStart` when `audioStart != 0`) but this didn't work. The same issue still occurred.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can keep the waveform consistent while scrolling it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Despite years of programming experience, I still can't seem to correctly round a number. It was as simple as that.

The line

```
if (audioStart != 0) {
    audioStart += packSize % audioStart;
}
```

should be

```
audioStart = (int) Mathf.Round(audioStart / packSize) * packSize;
```

Adding 1 extra byte to `waveform` is also necessary as half the time the rounding will cause there to be one extra sample included. As such, `waveform` should be defined as:

```
float[] waveform = new float[textWidth+1];
```

This solves the issue and the samples are chosen consistently. I'm not quite sure how programs like audacity manage to get nice looking waveforms that aren't super noisy (comparison below for the same song: mine on top, audacity below) but that's for another question.

[image]